# Almost nondecreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real sequence. Suppose 
$$\forall j~\exists n_j:n>n_j\Rightarrow a_n-a_{n+1}<\dfrac1{2^j}$$
I wonder if there has to be a $\max_{j}\{n_{j+1}-n_j\}$ or the gaps can go to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac12,\frac14,\frac14,\frac18,\frac18,\frac18,\frac1{16},\frac1{16},\frac1{16},\frac1{16},\frac1{32},\dots$, so $\frac1{2^n}$ occurs $n$ times.

The "gaps" will clearly get bigger and bigger.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!